# YAML rendering index.html every time any PHP is called on gCloud App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, yaml

I am learning how to move my existing PHP project to gCloud.
For the same, I created an AppEngine project and have placed my code there.

Everything seems to work except the PHP files.

When I launch my project, the index files launches (as specified in app.yaml) and then where the PHP should execute, it's renders the index.html file. This creates a deadly loop of index calling PHP calling index calling PHP :(

I am sure I have my app.yaml wrong, but am unable to figure out where the problem is.

My yaml looks like this:

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
handlers:  
- url: /dialpad_research/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/\1
  upload: dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))

- url: /dialpad_research/static
  static_dir: dialpad_research/static

# image files
- url: /dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
# dialpad root
- url: /dialpad_research.*
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/index.html
  upload: dialpad_research/static/index.html

- url: /dialpad_research/api/(.+\.php)$
  script: api/\1
```

Any help is appreciated.

Folder structure is like this:

```
Root
|
---- app.yaml
---- dialpad_research (folder)
     |
     ---- static (folder with index file)
     ---- api (folder with PHP files)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to be careful with your regex matching.  This url pattern:

```
- url: /dialpad_research/static
```

will match:

```
- url: /dialpad_research/static(anything to follow)
```

So, it will never get to the handler below:

```
- url: /dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

Same for:

```
- url: /dialpad_research.*
```

After that, it can never get to:

```
- url: /dialpad_research/api/(.+\.php)$
```

Reorder your handlers so that they don't short-circuit.

Next, `/api/` and `/static/` are not at the root so your paths to them are incorrect.  See below:

```
handlers:  
- url: /dialpad_research/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))
  mime_type: text/cache-manifest
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/\1
  upload: dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(appcache|manifest))

# image files
- url: /dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/\1
  upload: dialpad_research/static/(.*\.(bmp|gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))

- url: /dialpad_research/api/(.+\.php)$
  script: dialpad_research/api/\1

- url: /dialpad_research/static
  static_dir: dialpad_research/static

# dialpad root
- url: /dialpad_research.*
  static_files: dialpad_research/static/index.html
  upload: dialpad_research/static/index.html
```

Comment: Thanks. When I do these changes, now none of my images are showing up. The path shown in the browser inspector is correct, but it says 404 file not found for all images.

Comment: OK, so I see your 2nd error.  `/static/` is not at the root, so `upload: static/(...)` will not be found.  Updating answer

Comment: btw. can someone tell me why they marked down my question negative?????